# Continuously speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I'm currently working on a project where I need to create some functionality where the user can talk to the product (Raspberry Pi 3). And with talking I mean that the user should be able to say one or two words something like *"product start"* to the Pi and then it would get activated and do it's thing.

Now because of this, the Pi would need to be able to continuously listen and get activated when a certain combination of words is said by the user.

I've implemented the [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) library, this sort of works but sadly there is a maximum of ~10 seconds where the Pi would listen.

I'm wondering if there are any library's which would help me with my use case, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain better what do you mean by

> sadly there is a maximum of ~10 seconds where the Pi would listen.

From my experience using CMUSphinx (Let me recomend the pocketsphinx version for your use-case), works continuously without problem.
Did you manage to know if the problem is on the Pi side, or the SpeechRecognition side?

What engine are you using behind SpeehRecognition. CMUSphinx, Google, Microsoft? With Google and Microsoft, it iis normal that they have a 10 seconds limitation. However, using CMUSphinx this should not happen. But, you might need to learn a bit how to set up an ASR system.

Comment: Thanks for your response. With ~10 seconds I ment that, from the moment I execute the Python script my Raspberry Pi will listen for about 10 seconds. Now this is not a problem with the Pi itself, this is on the SpeechRecognition side, I've found out that the 10 seconds is sort of the maximum it will recognize. Now you mentioned Pocketsphinx, I read a bit about it, but I did not not it was able to listen continuously. Do you know if it is able to recognize directly from a microphone? Or does it only recognize from a WAV file. Also do you have any good tutorials for Pocketsphinx by any chance?